# How do you handle Accessibility gestures in a pure TypeScript React Native component?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, accessibility

I have a custom slider component with a PanResponder for capturing events to adjust the slider. It works as expected when the screen reader is not active. I'm supporting iOS/Android.

React Native Accessibility docs provide APIs for setting an accessibility label and some OS specific traits to indicate to the user information about the control, but I don't see a means to handle the gestures required. For example, on iOS setting the trait 'adjustable' causes VoiceOver to tell the user to "Swipe up and down" to change values. PanResponder doesn't seem to have any kind of event mapping to make the control actually respond that way.

Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: Can you post your code? Try to be more specific. What's the behavior you are you expecting? What is the result you are seeing?

Comment: Regarding iOS, if you get to an element that is adjustable, sometimes you have to change your rotor setting to "adjust value" (sometimes it's changed for you), and then swiping up/down will change the value.  Your slider should get an update event as if the user clicked or dragged the slider thumb with a mouse.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the exact same problem.